# Prepare / read authenticated user claims from HttpContext.User

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, httpcontext

```
var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("External");

if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest();

var email = authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);

var id = _usersService.Create(email.Value);

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id", id.ToString()));

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Application", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
```

In controllers the following line throws *Sequence contains no elements* in controllers:

```
var idClaim = HttpContext.User?.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "id").Single();
```

I call `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` in `Startup` and I thought that the first snippet would set cookies and then `User` would provide access to it on every client request but it doesn't work.

If I put a breakpoint right after `SiginInAsync` then `HttpContext.User` contains the expected claim but not in other calls.

`HttpContext.Request.Cookies` is empty. In browser I see several cookies among them `.AspNetCore.External` and `.AspNetCore.Application` plus some antiforgery cookies.

How do I achieve having claims in `User` for all requests after authentication was done?

Can it be the problem that my front-end runs on a separate port? [Probably not.](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/)

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps below to add updated claims to `HttpContext.User`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65319557/11398810

Then you can get claims in other request:

```
var idClaim = HttpContext.User?.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "id").Single();
```

Comment: Not sure that is what I need. I don't use Identity and EF. I will be able to do more investigation next weekend.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you don't use Identity? The call to `UseAuthentication` sets up ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: @SnailCadet according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authappbuilderextensions.useauthentication?view=aspnetcore-5.0) it adds authentication middleware. This middleware might use Identity and might not.