# Update logged Identity claims when add new claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I have a .net core web api application with angular. I use AspNetCore Identity. I have a claim table with userId and value colums. The createnewuser method call from angular site, and they call to register user method. There no any problem here.

I wanna add new claim into `httpcontext current user claims` list.
I'd tried but it is not help me.

> [Added a claim to an existing HttpContext User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296548/added-a-claim-to-an-existing-httpcontext-user)

But I can see added new claim into `_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Claims` when re-authenticate with new token. How can I see add new claim into current identity (`_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Claims`)?

And I got current user Id value from httpontext.

```
var parentId = _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == "uid");
                     if (parentId != null && parentId.Value != null)
                     {
                        await _IdentityService.AddClaimAsync(new RegisterRequest()
                         {
                          "newclaim" = "new-claim-key",
                          userId = parentId.Value
                      });
```

Comment: did you check it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587414/how-to-update-a-claim-in-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best wasy get claims from db who logged used like that:

```
var claimList = userManager.
GetClaimsAsync(await_userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContext.HttpContext.User))
```

Although this is not a very accurate method, it is the most reliable method. This way you can get the latest claim list in db